# Creating a Upvote Component as a Functional Component

Tags: reactjs

So I am practicing changing my Upvote class component to a functional component. Below is my work in progress. Ultimately I would like to handle the upvote/downvote changes through one onClick handler. Please let me know what I need to change in my code in order to do so. Thanks!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Upvote = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const handleClick = () => {
        if (count === 0){
            setCount(0) 
        } else if (count === 1){
            <span>{decrement}</span>
        } else {
            <span>{increment}</span>
        }

    }

    const increment = () => {
        setCount(count + 1)
    }

    const decrement = () => {
        setCount(count - 1)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>
                {count}
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Upvote;
```

Comment: So, what error is this giving?

Comment: The button appeared but when I click it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your functional component. Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Upvote = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const increment = () => {
        setCount(count + 1)
    }

    const decrement = () => {
        setCount(count - 1)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={increment}>
                Increment
            </button>
            <button onClick={decrement}>
                Decrement
            </button>
            <div>{count}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Upvote;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What if I just want to limit the amount a user can upvote/downvote. Since its for the current user, I would like to cap it at 1 and when they downvote -1.

Comment: You can add a `disabled` attribute to the `<button />`
For increment: `disabled={count === 1}`
For decrement: `disabled={count === -1}`

Comment: Hey Nemanja, so I tried that but I'm getting errors. Please see below:     return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={increment} disabled={count ==== 1}>
                Increment
            </button>
            <button  onClick={decrement} disabled={count === -1}>
                Decrement
            </button>
            <div>{count}</div>
        </div>
    )

Comment: You have `====` one extra `=` sign. Use either 3 or just 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your logic, as I can see the count state will never increase. This is how the handleClick function is supposed to be

```
const handleClick = () => {
    if (count === 0){
        setCount(count + 1)
    } else {
        setCount(count - 1)
    }
}
```

You don't need the increment and decrement function